# Receiving parameters from another application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, struts2

I have 2 applications and when I click some link go to another and login in it. The first App is in Spring and the other is in Struts2. I redirect well but I don't know how to send the username and password from Spring to Struts.

Spring app jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<div id="nav" class="ui-corner-left">
    <ul>

        <li class="nav_openreports" id="nav_openreports">
            <a href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/SpringMethod/goToStrutsApp" target="_blank">

            </a><span><spring:message code="label.StrutsApp"/></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Spring app controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/SpringMethod/goToStrutsApp", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String goToStrutsApp(final Model model, final HttpSession session) {

        final String dominio = this.prop.getProperty("app.url");
        final String urlDestino = dominio + this.prop.getProperty("url.strutsApp");

        return "redirect:" + urlDestino;
    }
```

Struts app Login.action

```
private Map<Object,Object> session;

    protected String userName;
    protected String password;

    protected UserProvider userProvider;

    @Override
    public String execute()
    {
        if (userName == null || userName.length() < 1 || 
                password == null || password.length() < 1)
        {
            addActionError(getText(LocalStrings.ERROR_LOGIN_INCOMPLETE));
            return INPUT;
        }

        try
        {
            ReportUser user = checkCredentials();

            System.out.println("user: "+user);

            if (user == null)
            {
                addActionError(getText(LocalStrings.ERROR_LOGIN_INVALID));              
                return INPUT;
            }

            session.put("user", user);
            ActionContext.getContext().setLocale(user.getLocale());

            if (user.isDashboardUser() && 
                (user.getDefaultReport() != null || user.getAlerts().size() > 0))
            {
                return ORStatics.DASHBOARD_ACTION;
            }

            return SUCCESS;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            addActionError(e.toString());
            return INPUT;
        }
    }

    /**
     * checkCredentials - override this method to customize login authentication
     * @return ReportUser, if credentials in order, null otherwise
     * @throws ProviderException
     */
    protected ReportUser checkCredentials() throws ProviderException {
        return userProvider.getUser(userName, password);        
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void setSession(Map session) 
    {
        this.session = session;
    }

    public String getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }

    public String getUserName()
    {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName)
    {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public void setUserProvider(UserProvider userProvider)
    {
        this.userProvider = userProvider;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is a correct and accepted way or not. But I'm certain that this will work.

Follow below steps:

1. From spring application when you click on goToStrutsApp, this should
   go to another spring controller which will register a temp token in
   database (a random token/or token generated using username and password may be 32 digit token,
   eg:abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzasdfgh) and forward the request to struts login page with temp token as param param(as query string which shows request is coming from another application) .
2. In struts logic access check if it is coming from another application using if the param exists in HttpServletRequest.
3. Extract the token from HttpServletRequest (param) and check in database if that token exists. If it exists then delete the token and bypass the login. create necessary cookies etc.

Hope this will help